# WIX hooks after insert not called

Tags: velo

I pasted this code to the data.js file.
and debugging with Site Monitoring, but afterInsert was not called and a new line was added.
what it could be?

```
export function Token_afterInsert(item, context) {
  let hookContext = context;  // see below
  // some changes to the received item
  console.log(item, hookContext,'afterInsert was calles' )
  return item;
}
```

Comment: What is your database `id`?

Comment: Database id  is Token

Comment: If there is no new item in your DB, then its an issue with the insert itself. After insert only fires on a successful DB insert. You can use onFailure to try to debug.

Comment: It's doesn't, when I tried to add a line manually (from the UI) it's working and   Token_afterInsert is called but when I use code new line is added but after insert or update insert doesn't call.